# timeout package for centos

Tags: ubuntu, centos, timeout

I am running a cron job which often hangs and does not respond. The same problem was mentioned at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2635002/372640)

I need timeout command for centos as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6065592/372640). Link for [ubuntu timeout command](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/timeout).

Comment: Have a look at this link: https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=31406

Comment: Link is dead. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in RHEL.  On my RHEL 5 System (abbreviated output):

```
# yum whatprovides */timeout
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
bash-3.2-32.el5.x86_64 : The GNU Bourne Again shell (bash) version 3.2
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-5
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/doc/bash-3.2/scripts/timeout
```

Check the above path to see if it's there.  If it is then copy the scirpt to somewhere in your path (easiest) or add the scripts directory to your path if that's appropriate for your environment (better).